# Proof of a theorem using field axioms

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-writing, field-theory

I need to prove that $(a/b)+(c/d)=(ad+bc)/(bd)$ if $b\ne0$ and $d\ne0.$
Here is what I've got 
$(a/b)+(c/d)=(ad+bc)/(bd)=(a(b)^{-1})(c(d)^{-1})=ac+a(d)^{-1}+c(b)^{-1}+(b)^{-1}(d)^{-1}$. But I don't know if it is correct.
Thanks a lot in advance!.

Comment: The second to last expression should be addition, should it not?

Comment: You are making a mistake of stating with your conclusion and working your way to a middle.  That never works and is always incorrect and invalind.  All that proves is you don't have an inconsistancy (and you don't even state that) and not that you have something true.  You need to start at the *beginning and never state *anything* you don't yet know and work to the end.  You start with a/b+c/d =(ad+bc)/bd.  You don't *know* that.  That's what you to *prove* that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer isn't quite correct.

Since we're working over a field, addition produces another element of the field. Let's call this $z.$

$$\dfrac{a}{b}+\dfrac{c}{d}=z.$$

Multiplying both sides by $b$ yields,

$$ad+bc=zbd$$
Dividing both sides by $bd$  yields

$$\dfrac{ad+bc}{bd}=z,$$

so we conclude

$$\dfrac{a}{b}+\dfrac{c}{d}=\dfrac{ad+bc}{bd},$$

as desired.